# Creating boolean subsets for a bar graph in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Pandas newbie here.

I currently have a (very busy) graph of respondents by US states which I made using this:

```
pstate.plot.bar(x='home_state',figsize=(30,10),fontsize=30)
```

I have a boolean value for the respondents that I would like to apply to each state, so each state bar would become two bars--one for number of panelists for which the value is true in X state, and one for which the number of panelists for which the value is false in X state.

For example, say there's ~250 AK respondents. In the new graph, there'd be two bars where there's currently one AK bar--a "false AK" bar that has 100 respondents and a "true AK" bar that has 150 respondents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated--and if there's more information I should provide, please let me know!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! It is a good idea to ask these questions with a bit of data and code for us to see what you are doing. See the guide on creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I believe you may want to use something along the lines of `pstate.groupby('my_boolean_column').sum().plot.bar()`

Comment: Hi @Sam! Good to know, I'll provide more code next time. The problem I run into with the above code is that I'm working with a big data set of individual panelists--I made pstate from the original dataset p using the command `pstate = p.groupby("home_state").home_state.count()` which means it doesn't have the boolean column in it any more. Thanks so much!